# How Generic Works in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Question 1 - Why not arrList1 stick to String only?

```
ArrayList arrList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
arrList1.add(10);
arrList1.add("Manish");
arrList1.add(0.234);
```

---

Question 2 - No Compilation error but giving run-type error why?

```
ArrayList<String> arrList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
arrList2 = arrList1;
```

---

Question 3 - What is the use of below?

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrList3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrList2 = arrList3; //compiler error that's fine
```

---

Question 4 - How to do operation on arrList4?

```
ArrayList<?> arrList4 = new ArrayList<String>();
//arrList4.add("String"); //compilation error?

arrList4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrList4.add(23); //compilation error?
```

---

Question 5 - What is use generic in assigning object then as its not work? Like in arrList1?

```
ArrayList<String> arrList5 = new ArrayList();
arrList5.add("String");
arrList5.add(23.3); //compilation error that's fine
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1) generics are a compile time check. You implicitly cast the ArrayList to a raw type so the compiler has no idea how you created it. Why is this allowed? For backward compatibility. It had to work with code written without generics. Eg Java 1.4.2

Q2) you get a runtime error getting elements out which are not String as they don't match the type it expects.

Q3) a wild card is an unknown type. It doesn't mean it matches anything. If you have a `? extends T` and you *get* this all you know it is a T. In many ways the ? makes it read only and it is only useful for return values.

Q4) You made it an ArrayList of Integer so you have to add an Integer or int which can be boxed to Integer.

Q5) there is compile time and run time checks. There a way to bypass the compile time checks in almost every case (some more obscure that others). In the first example you have turned off the compiler's ability to check the code for you so you see errors at runtime instead. It's like you said to the compiler, trust me I know what I am doing.
 The compiler will still warn you when you do this although you can turn this off too with `@SuppressWarnings("checked")`

Comment: Answer for Q4 is not working... arrList4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
arrList4.add(new Integer(23)); //giving compilation error

Comment: In Q1, I m adding string, int, double. It is not checking at compile time but it should check at run time for String (as ArrayList arrList1 = new ArrayList<String>() ) but its work fine. it iterate and display. Why???

Comment: @ManishAgrawal your type is `ArrayList<?>` so you can't add anything to the list.

Comment: @ManishAgrawal you are adding a String, an Integer and a Double. When the toString is called, it is treating them as Object. What you can't do is treat them as String.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is taking all element as object. If it is taking as Object then what's the use of <String> Generic in ArrayList arrList1 = new ArrayList<String>() ?? How generic will come into picture here??

Comment: @ManishAgrawal the generic is only meaningful if you don't cast it away and ignore warning when you do. Note in java 7 you can use the diamond operator ie `new ArrayList<>();`